# Sumar el total de números de una consulta

Tags: sql, oracle

Quiero obtener la suma de todos los datos que recupere de una consulta con sub consultas. Esta seria la consulta

```
SELECT p.run ||'-'|| p.dv AS "RUN POSTULANTE", p.nombre AS NOMBRE, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,p.fecha_nacimiento)/12) AS EDAD,
(SELECT puntaje 
FROM syn_p_pjecuantitativo
WHERE TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,p.fecha_nacimiento)/12) BETWEEN VALOR_MINIMO AND VALOR_MAXIMO AND criterio_id_criterio = 
                                                                          (SELECT ID_CRITERIO
                                                                           FROM syn_p_criterio
                                                                           WHERE DESCRIPCION = 'Edad')) AS "PTJE. EDAD",
est.descripcion AS "EST. CIVIL", est.puntaje AS "PTJE. EST. CIVIL",
CASE WHEN p.puebloorig_pueblo_id IN 
                               (SELECT pueblo_id
                                FROM syn_p_puebloorig
                                WHERE pueblo_nombre IN ('PICUNCHES','MAPUCHES','HUILLICHES','RAPANUI','DIAGUITAS','ATACAMEÑOSS',
                                'CAUCAHUÉS'))
THEN 'Si'
ELSE 'No' 
END AS "PUEBLO IND. ORIG.",
NVL(pue.pueblo_puntaje,0) AS "PTJE. PUEBLO IND. ORIG.",
r.region_puntaje AS "PTJE. ZONA EXTRENA",
(SELECT puntaje 
FROM syn_p_pjecuantitativo
WHERE po.nota_pregrado BETWEEN VALOR_MINIMO AND VALOR_MAXIMO AND criterio_id_criterio = 
                                                         (SELECT ID_CRITERIO
                                                         FROM syn_p_criterio
                                                         WHERE DESCRIPCION = 'Antecedentes acadÃ©micos')) AS "PJE. ANTEC. ACAD"                                       
FROM syn_p_postulante p JOIN syn_p_postulacion po ON(p.run = po.postulante_run)
JOIN syn_p_est_estadocivil est ON(po.estadocivil_estcivil_id = est.estcivil_id)
LEFT JOIN syn_p_puebloorig pue ON(pue.pueblo_id = p.puebloorig_pueblo_id)
JOIN syn_p_comuna c ON(po.comuna_comuna_id = c.comuna_id)
JOIN syn_p_region r ON(c.region_region_id = r.region_id)
JOIN syn_p_institucion ins ON (ins.instacad_id = po.institucion_instacad_id);
```

Y este es el resultado de la consulta, la idea es que al final de la consulta este la suma de todos los puntajes, que en este caso serian "PTJE. EDAD", "PTJE. EST. CIVIL", "PTJE. PUEBLO IND. ORIG.", "PTJE. ZONA EXTRENA" y "PJE. ANTEC. ACAD", como lo muestro recalcado en rojo.

[image: Resultado de la consulta, con la columna en rojo que quiero obtener]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que los más sencillo sería emplear una Common Table Expression (CTE)

Sería algo así

```
WITH CTE AS (
   <Tu consulta aquí>
)
SELECT CTE.*, <Suma de campos que quieras> AS TOTAL FROM CTE;
```

Dado que tu consulta es bastante compleja, permite que la simplifique un poco para que veas a que me refiero con este ejemplo.

```
CREATE TABLE puntos (
  ID NUMBER,
  SUMANDO_1 NUMBER NOT NULL,
  SUMANDO_2 NUMBER NOT NULL,
  SUMANDO_3 NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);


INSERT INTO puntos (ID, SUMANDO_1, SUMANDO_2, SUMANDO_3) VALUES(1, 2, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO puntos (ID, SUMANDO_1, SUMANDO_2, SUMANDO_3) VALUES(2, 5, 6, 7);
INSERT INTO puntos (ID, SUMANDO_1, SUMANDO_2, SUMANDO_3) VALUES(3, 8, 9, 10);
```

Consulta

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ID, SUMANDO_1 AS "PTOS 1", SUMANDO_2 AS "PTOS 2", SUMANDO_3 AS "PTOS 3"
  FROM PUNTOS
  )
 SELECT CTE.*, CTE."PTOS 1" + CTE."PTOS 2" + CTE."PTOS 3" AS TOTAL
 FROM CTE;
```

Resultado

```
ID  PTOS 1  PTOS 2  PTOS 3  TOTAL
1   2       3       4       9
2   5       6       7       18
3   8       9       10      27
```

CTE es una alias igual que los que tú has empleado, la palabra reservada para la operación en oracle es **WITH**.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, lo que necesitas es añadir una columna más cuyo valor corresponde con la suma de otros campos de esa misma línea. Por lo tanto, para incluir una nueva columna, sólo tienes que añadir un nuevo campo a la SELECT principal.

Justo delante de ...FROM syn_p_postulante p JOIN.... debes incluir esa nueva columna que se definiría como:

```
("PTJE. EDAD" + "PTJE. EST. CIVIL" + "PTJE. PUEBLO IND. ORIG." + "PTJE. ZONA EXTRENA" + "PJE. ANTEC. ACAD") AS "PTJE.TOTAL"
```